What is galaxy internal velocity anisotropy?
I came across this term in this paper, where the authors propose using galaxy velocity anisotropy to classify galaxies.
What does this term refer to?
Is it just the difference between stars and gases velocities at different distances from the galactic centre? Or does it refer to another thing?
Thanks in advance

Are you talking about velocities of galaxies or velocities of stars inside a galaxy?

The previous version of the question was not very clear; now I tried to explain myself better

The question is substantially improved, and clearlhy answerable now. Boting to leave open.

Isotropic means the same in all directions. If all galaxies you observe move in random directions, their velocities are isotropic. If most galaxies appear to be moving in the same direction, then the velocity distribution is anisotropic, i.e. there is a preferred direction to the velocity vectors.

I'm sorry, the previous version of the question was not very clear. Now I tried to explain myself better; it's not about galaxy groups or anything like that, more on the internal velocities of matter in a single galaxy
